# simple method for getting the text of all JtextField

Tags: java, swing, persistence, jtextfield

I have to save the textField everytime I clicked the SAVE button.. So, currently I'm doing getText() method.. It is so suffering because I got a lot of textField to be saved. Moreover, I want to save the textField.getText() into text file then.

```
public static String tf20;
public static String tf21;
public static String tf22;
public static String tf23;
public static String tf24; 

public static JTextField textField_20;
public static JTextField textField_21;
public static JTextField textField_22;
public static JTextField textField_23;
public static JTextField textField_24;    

tf20=textField_20.getText();//Is there any simple method? 
tf21=textField_21.getText();
tf22=textField_22.getText();
tf23=textField_23.getText();
tf24=textField_24.getText();
```

My question  is, is there any simple method for getting the text of all textField  such as

> tf[j]=textField[i].getText(); ?

Comment: [Introduction to JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) AND I'd learn, very fast, to do without `static`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make an array of JTextField. But you should be aware of errors -- even if you declared an array of JTextField, there is no JTextField object in the array. You need to construct each JTextField object when you initialize the array.
[how to create an Array of JTextField](http://www.coderanch.com/t/367570/java/java/create-Array-JTextField)

Answer (score 0):

The simple example:

```
public class Test {

    JTextField[] allTextFields;

    public Test() {
        allTextFields = new JTextField[]{
            new JTextField("Text 1"),
            new JTextField("Text 2"),
            new JTextField("Text 3"),
            new JTextField("Text 4"), //...
        };

        //...
        for (JTextField jTextField : allTextFields) {
            String currentText = jTextField.getText();
        }

    }
}
```

You can also create some kind of a map, which will store pairs `<String, JTextField>`, so you can easily access the particular textfield (`map.getValue("TXT_A")`) as well as iterate through all of them:

```
public class Test {

    private Map<String, JTextField> map = new HashMap<String, JTextField>();

    public Test() {
        map.put("TXT_1", new JTextField());
        map.put("TXT_2", new JTextField());
        map.put("TXT_3", new JTextField());
        // etc...

        // Access:
        String value = map.get("TXT_1").getText();

        // Iteration:
        for (Map.Entry<String, JTextField> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            JTextField currentTextField = entry.getValue();
            String currentString = currentTextField.getText();
        }

    }
}
```